# Facebook Canvas Authentication with Sinatra: Signed Cookie (with Rack)

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, rack, session-cookies

I want to create a secure cookie and sign it with my Facebook app's secret that only I know, according to [Facebook signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas).

I already implemented a [Ruby method that decodes the signed_request sent by Facebook](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/loversapp.com/blob/master/lib/lovers/user.rb#L11).

That works, but now, as [runwithfriends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas) does, I want to send the client back a cookie that uses the same signing procedure.

I was looking through the [rack source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb#L24), and it looks like it provides this functionality.

I'm wondering, however, how to do this in Sinatra. It looks like `set_cookie` is a wrapper around [`set_cookie_headers`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L177), which does not seem to accept a secret. So, I think I have to do it with Rack. I'll try that and report back.

In the mean time, the [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/) says that it provides session based cookies.

So, what's the difference then between setting a cookie:

```
set_cookie("u", 123)
```

or setting a session variable:

```
session["u"] = 123
```

I found myself digging through the Sinatra & Rack source code. I have an idea. I think they're pretty much the same besides certain default features.

Answer (score 2):

One option.

I would recommend using a server-side "session" solution for a facebook app like this. https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store for example gives you a Sinatra "cache" object that you can store serialized objects in. And you can set expirations for the redis keys so that memory doesn't build up too much. I would recommend using the facebook uid as the key for the cache such that no matter what computer/browser a user is using, her session will always be the same. Also, this way you don't have to worry about setting cookies in iframes, which doesn't work in Safari and Chrome.

Before filter: `@session = cache.fetch("session-#{@uid}") { {} }`

After filter: `cache.set("session-#{@uid}", @session)`